# Groovy and XMLUnit: compare webservice results

Tags: web-services, rest, groovy, xmlunit

Using Groovy and XMLUnit I am trying to write a script to compare the xml output of web services from multiple endpoints. Attempting to get it working from one endpoint then iterate over endpoints to compare output, however, I continue to get the following error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
Could not find matching constructor for: 
     org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff(groovy.util.Node, groovy.util.Node)
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
Could not find matching constructor for: 
     org.custommonkey.xmlunit.Diff(groovy.util.Node, groovy.util.Node)
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with my inexperience with both XmlParser/XmlSlurper and XMLUnit (a.k.a. newbie). I greatly appreciate any pointers in the right direction. Here is sample code that causes the exception:

```
@Grab(group='xmlunit', module='xmlunit', version='1.5')
import org.custommonkey.xmlunit.*

def url = "http://www.webservicex.net//geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP?IPAddress=173.201.44.188"
def xmlParserResults = new XmlParser().parse("$url")
//same thing happens if I use...
//def xmlSlurperResults = new XmlSlurper().parse("$url")

def xmlDiff = new Diff(xmlParserResults, xmlParserResults)
assert xmlDiff.identical()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url returns xml and `Diff` takes two Strings to compare (in your case you are comparing Nodes). So the easiest way to compare would be to use [URL](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/net/URL.html) instead of trying it to parse using `XmlParser` or `XmlSlurper`.

```
def url = 
"http://www.webservicex.net//geoipservice.asmx/GetGeoIP?IPAddress=173.201.44.188"
def xmlString = new URL(url).text

def xmlDiff = new Diff(xmlString, xmlString)
assert xmlDiff.identical()
```

In case the above is just a sample and not a working example of hitting multiple endpoints then the point is to represent the xml output as string and then compare.

Comment: Oh my word I can't believe it is even easier than I thought it! Thank you very much dmahapatro!